# If cell contains specific text then push function to the cell to the right if it doesn't contain specific text

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add another condition to the script below to read if the cell it's targeting for the formula = a specific company name, then do not push the function in the cell? Thanks!

```
For Each cellAR In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If InStr(cellAR.Text, "Company") > 0 Then
      cellAR.Offset(0, 1) = "=CONCATENATE('Company'!B17)"
    End If
Next cellAR
```

My attempt:

```
For Each cellAR In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
  If InStr(cellAR.Text, "Company") > 0 And cellAR.Offset(0, 1) = "Company a" Then
    cellAR.Offset(0, 1) = "=CONCATENATE('Company'!B17)"
  End If
Next cellAR
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:

For Each cellAR In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If InStr(cellAR.Text, "Company") > 0 And cellAR.Offset(0, 1) <> "Company Name" Then
      cellAR.Offset(0, 1) = "=CONCATENATE('Company'!B17)"
    End If
Next cellAR

but it doesn't like it. I get a runtime error on the second line of code.

Comment: Can you share sample data? A little confused if what you have is the working code you want to update or your attempt to make the update. Also, you are concatenating a single cell which means you are just returning the cell

Comment: The second code is my update to try to get it working with the AND operator. I have a cell that is connected to 2 different forms which captured the company from both. Only 1 form will be used and the other deleted. This code is pushing the formula into the cell from the form which is not deleted. There are other tables with <Company Name> on that same sheet where the formula is being injected with pre-filled company. What I'm trying to do is if the text value "Company" is in Col A And the cell to the right is not equal to "Company A", then it injects the formula in the cell to the right.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Btw your AND clause has an equal - should that be no equal?

Comment: If you're gonna write a formula in a cell programatically, use 'cellAR.FormulaLocal = "=CONCATENATE('Company'!B17)"' or whatever command/function 'string' you need.  Though it is a bit odd to concatenate a single value.